# Getting Type mismatch Error in VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I have a code, something like this :

```
Public Sub Match()

    ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Activate

    Range("Data!H8") = Application.Sum(Application.Index(Range("A:GH"), 0, Application.Match("ORDERS" & "Country", Range("B2:B100") & Range("A2:GH2"), 0)))

End Sub
```

When I run this code I'm getting a error "Type Mismatch". Can anybody help me with this?
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HSC77.png)

Comment: You can't do array type formulas in vba like this.  Use Evaluate and put the actual formula in.

Comment: Does the formula work if you enter it in the Sheet directly? You are concatenating a vertical range and a horizontal range that do not have the same number of cells.  This would return errors.

Comment: @ScottCraner Thanks for the reply, actually this formula didnt wrk when i did in sheet directly, Actually iam trying to get the summary table , so iam trying to get sum of certain columns in another sheet by looking its column and row heading instead of Cell reference, here ORDERS are my rows and Country is my column, THankss

Comment: Hard to give you an answer without more information on the data in your spreadsheet. but at first glance I would say look up =sumifs and =countifs functions.

Comment: Then your first question should be; "what formula would I need?"  To ask this you will need to mock up some data and expected output.

Comment: @Scott Craner I have added a image of my sample file hope this will help to get a idea abt the data, thanks

Comment: @ClintB Thanks for ur reply, I have tried sumif before but it didnt really work for me, i have added a image for a better understanding of the datas thanks :)

Comment: Look into sumproduct

Answer (score 0):

What you are trying to do can be done. But its not simple because of the way your data is represented. Here is an example of how I was able to acheive your goal.

I used Column I as the country you are trying to sum.
 - I3 I search for this country which returns the column number.
 - I4 I convert this number to letter
 - I5 Do the sumifs formula (using the indirect formula to tell it to use the found column (C in this example) as the sum column. Where column "A" = "orders"

Forumlas used are in column J.

[image: Example]